# Magento 2 : Issues with sub categories

Tags: category, products, category-products, magento-2.1.9

I have an issue while adding sub categories.Its showing 1 in addition to the category name i.e subcategory 1 and the products are not reflecting at the front end. please help me on that as I am new to magento.

Comment: Please add more info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be indexing problem. Run following commands to reset and reindex your indexes.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod 777 -R var pub
```